# Between metacompactness and infinite Lebesgue covering dimension

Tags: general-topology

A space $(X,\tau)$ is said to be *metacompact* if every open covering $\cal U$ has a refinement $\cal V$ such that for every $x\in X$ the set ${\cal V}_x := \{V\in \mathcal{V}: x\in V\}$ is finite.

A space $(X,\tau)$ is said to have *Lebesgue dimension $\leq n$* (for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$) if every open covering $\cal U$ has a refinement $\cal V$ such that for every $x\in X$ the set ${\cal V}_x := \{V\in \mathcal{V}: x\in V\}$ has at less than $n$ elements. (Note that $n$ is "globally fixed" for all open coverings $\cal U$.) If there is no $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(X,\tau)$ has Lebesgue dimension $\leq n$ then $(X,\tau)$ is said to have infinite Lebesgue dimension.

Is there a metacompact space with infinite Lebesgue dimension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the coproduct (topological sum) $X = \coprod_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{R}^n$.

- As a sum of metacompact (even paracompact) spaces, $X$ is itself metacompact (even paracompact).
- As $\dim ( \mathbb{R}^n ) = n$ for each $n$, then $X$ must have infinite Lebesgue covering dimension..